# Creating a remote branch with no (previous) local history

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch in my computer but I would like to create a new branch with no history at all (just one commit initially) and using this new branch on the remote side. How can I do that?

For example local branch has:

**commit1**, **commit2**, **commit3**

But I want my new branch to have only **commit0** that is the code of the last state (**commit3**), with no previous history. I wish then to merge stuff easily for example if I do **commit4** in my local branch, I wish to have only **commit0** and **commit4** changes in the remote branch.

How the best way to achieve this? I want mainly "compress" the stuff in the remote branch and not necessarely erase the history in my local one, to be able to still work on the local one.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to squash your commits, maybe on a different branch: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189560/184546

Comment: What if you **clone** the repo to a new folder? Then you have the most current status without further commits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want my new branch to have only commit0 that is the code of the last state (commit3), with no previous history.

You can get this pretty easily:

```
git checkout commit3    # get index and work-tree set up
git status              # make sure you're on commit3 and things are otherwise clean
```

then:

```
git checkout --orphan new-branch
git commit
```

and you have this new `commit0` on a new branch, with no history behind it: `commit0` is a new *root commit*.

> I wish then to merge stuff easily for example if I do commit4 in my local branch, I wish to have only commit0 and commit4 changes in the remote branch.

You *cannot* get this at all.  You *can* set things up so that you have commit0 and then commit5, where commit5's snapshot matches commit4's snapshot and has commit0 as its parent.  But commit4—the commit with *that* hash ID—has commit3 as its parent, forever.  Hash IDs are universal across *all* Git repositories, and no part of any commit can ever be changed, including its parent linkage.

It's important to realize that the word *branch*, in Git, is ambiguous: see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Sometimes *branch* means *chain of commits, terminated by one specific commit*.  Sometimes it means *branch name*.  Git repositories all have their own private branch names, so there's no reason that `master` in the Git repository reachable at URL `$url1` has to name the same commit that `master` in the Git repository at `$url2` names.

The histories, however, *are* the commits.  Merge works by using the history.  If two chains-of-commits don't connect, there is nothing to merge.

Git does allow you to build your own solutions: it's a tool-set, not a solution in itself.  You could write *your own* Git commands that let you add a new snapshot to a branch name of your choice, without using any of the existing commits in your actual working branches.  This might let you build the device you want:

```
git my-private-copy-to new-branch <commit-specifier>
```

would run your `git-my-private-copy-to` command, which would add a new commit using a tree (from argument 2) to the specified branch (argument 1).  Note that in the command I'm imagining—which does not exist but would just be a small shell script—there is no *merging* involved.

Since the command does not exist and you must write it, if you would like merging, you can put that in the command you write—but a standard merge uses, and adds to, the history recorded in the commit graph or subgraph, and you've deliberately made sure that your main work and this `new-branch` subgraph are disjoint subgraphs.

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't want merging after reading your answer. The command is a smart approach but I can only think in a rough copy-paste files from one branch to another i feel that isn't correct. If you can give some clues of potential useful git-[command] or answers that may help to create the command / generate that commit5 I'd be very appreciated.

Comment: Cherry-picking is actually a specific form of merging: it is a method by which Git will apply the parent-to-child changes (the child being the commit you cherry-pick) to the current commit, but it does so using the merge engine, treating the parent as the merge base. The `--strategy=recursive` is the default. The `--stdin` means it will read the commit hash IDs of the (multiple) commits to cherry-pick from stdin. You might be able to use `git commit-tree` as a simpler means of getting the results you want; it really depends on exactly what you want as the final snapshot.

Comment: For your `git rev-list`, you probably want `--topo-order --reverse` and a limiting range, if you do go with this method.

Comment: `git rev-list  --reverse localbranch | git cherry-pick -n  --strategy=recursive -X ours --stdin` I think this was the clue I was looking for generating that commit5. But ideally I would do this in a less "agressive way", I was able to `cherry-pick -n` commit by commit witouth "conflicts", but if I have like 2 commits bellow the `<commit-specifier>` I'd have to cherry pick those too.

Comment: Remember, each Git commit stores a full snapshot of its source. If you want to copy a snapshot, that's easy, because the commit just has one. If you want to turn a snapshot into changes, that's when `git diff` or `git cherry-pick` comes in, and then things get messier. Merging (or cherry-picking) involves combining work, which is harder but often more useful.